# Highlight an element when hovering on another?

Tags: javascript, python

I'd like to add this to my first web page.
Similar to what Chrome does in web inspector : Hovering and/or clicking an element highlights/selects a corresponding element.
I realized my page revolves around this and I can't advance without it. Any constructive advice would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: why is python tagged?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the position of the element you want to highlight relative to the position of the element to be hovered.

Take a look at this post:

[How to affect other elements when one element is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)

Once you know the position and have used the proper selector use:

```
background-color : lightblue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking about `:hover` in css, but without code it is difficult to get idea. Check below code:

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover {opacity: 1}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>
```